# Register a mock object inside a real object using Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class that needs to be tested, in which there are 2 objects contained inside, one is automatically created to connect to SQL server from the config file and the other is passed in from the constructor.

```
public class A{
  private SQLCon sqlcon;
  private RunObj runObj;

  public A (RunObj _runObj) {
    this.runObj = _runObj;
  }

  public void runA() {
    sqlcon.connect();
    runObj.run2();
  } 

}
```

I have created 2 test versions but both are not working. With @injectmock the object passed from constructor will be null.

```
    @Mock private SQLCon sqlcon;
    @Mock private RunObj runObj;
  
    @InjectMocks private A aobj = new A(runObj);

    @Test
    pulbic testA (){
       aobj.runA();
    }
```

but without using @injectmock, how can i register SQlcon as object inside of class A. For example:

```
    @Mock private SQLCon sqlcon;
    @Mock private RunObj runObj;
  
    private A aobj = new A(runObj);
    
    @Test
    pulbic testA (){
       aobj.runA();
    
   }
```

sqlcon inside class A is null.
How can I create a UT for this class A?

Comment: Remove `new A(rubObj)`. Mockito will create that instance and take care of injection.

Comment: you mean "private A aobj;" not @injectmock and not using constructor?

Comment: Using `@InjectMock` else Mockito doesn't know it needs to create an instance of it and inject the mocks.